# Flutter: Sorting ListView items based on type

Tags: json, listview, flutter

So I have a listview.builder in my Project management app in Flutter. This listview is filled with tasks(they can be: new, started, done). I get this data from an API and want the ones that are "new" to appear at the top, the ones that are started to be in the middle and the bottom for the "done" ones! - [This is how it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGbiB.png)
This is my *Class*, notice that I get the state from the API/JSON

```
class ProjectTask {
final int id;
final String description;
final String state;
final List assigned_users;
final List subtasks;

ProjectTask(this.id,
  this.description,
  this.state,
  this.assigned_users,
  this.subtasks);
}
```

The ListView

```
else return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

          if(snapshot.data[index].state == "done") {
            return Slidable(

              //SLIDABLE STUFF
              delegate: SlidableStrechDelegate(),
              actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
              actions: <Widget>[

                //ACTION ONE
                IconSlideAction(
                  caption: ("Information"),
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.black38,
                  icon: Icons.info,
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>projectTask(snapshot.data[index])));
                  },
                ),
              ],

              child: ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => projectTask(
                      snapshot.data[index],
                  )));
                },
                title: Text("${snapshot.data[index].description[0].toString().toUpperCase()}"
                    "${snapshot.data[index].description.toString().substring(1)}", maxLines: 1, style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 17)
                ),
                subtitle: Text("done"),
                leading: Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right, color: Colors.black54,),
              ),
            );
          }
          else if(snapshot.data[index].state == "started") {
            return Slidable(

              //SLIDABLE STUFF
              delegate: SlidableStrechDelegate(),
              actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
              actions: <Widget>[
                //ACTION ONE
                IconSlideAction(
                  caption: ("Information"),
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.black38,
                  icon: Icons.info,
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>projectTask(snapshot.data[index])));
                  },
                ),
              ],
              secondaryActions: <Widget>[

                //ACTION TWO
                IconSlideAction(
                  caption: ("Complete Me"),
                  color: Colors.green,
                  icon: Icons.radio_button_checked,
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>projectTask(snapshot.data[index])));
                  },
                )
              ],

              child: ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => projectTask(
                    snapshot.data[index],
                  )));
                },
                title: Text("${snapshot.data[index].description[0].toString().toUpperCase()}"
                    "${snapshot.data[index].description.toString().substring(1)}", maxLines: 1, style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 17)
                ),
                subtitle: Text("working"),
                leading: Icon(Icons.radio_button_checked, color: Colors.blue),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right, color: Colors.black54,),
              ),
            );
          }
          else {
            return Slidable(

              //SLIDABLE STUFF
              delegate: SlidableStrechDelegate(),
              actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
              actions: <Widget>[
                //ACTION ONE
                IconSlideAction(
                  caption: ("Information"),
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.black38,
                  icon: Icons.info,
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>projectTask(snapshot.data[index])));
                  },
                ),
              ],
              secondaryActions: <Widget>[

                //ACTION TWO
                IconSlideAction(
                  caption: ("Start Work"),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  icon: Icons.radio_button_checked,
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>projectTask(snapshot.data[index])));
                  },
                )
              ],

              //LISTTILE
              child: ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => projectTask(
                    snapshot.data[index],
                  )));
                },
                title: Text("${snapshot.data[index].description[0].toString().toUpperCase()}"
                    "${snapshot.data[index].description.toString().substring(1)}", maxLines: 1, style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 17)
                ),
                subtitle: Text("new"),
                leading: Icon(Icons.radio_button_checked, color: Colors.red),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right, color: Colors.black54,),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
      );
```

JSON

```
[
{
    "id": 7,
    "description": "Finishedddddd",
    "state": "done",
    "assigned_users": [
        {
            "username": "hugo",
            "fullname": "Hugo Johnsson"
        }
    ],
    "subtasks": []
},
{
    "id": 9,
    "description": "Newwww task for Huuugo",
    "state": "started",
    "assigned_users": [
        {
            "username": "hugo",
            "fullname": "Hugo Johnsson"
        }
    ],
    "subtasks": []
},
{
    "id": 11,
    "description": "Google presentation om IKEAS ekonomi",
    "state": "done",
    "assigned_users": [
        {
            "username": "studentone",
            "fullname": "Student One"
        }
    ],
    "subtasks": []
},
{
    "id": 15,
    "description": "entail",
    "state": "new",
    "assigned_users": [],
    "subtasks": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "dasdasdasd"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "fsdfsdfsdf"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 17,
    "description": "gmmgmsgd",
    "state": "new",
    "assigned_users": [],
    "subtasks": []
},
{
    "id": 18,
    "description": "dasd",
    "state": "started",
    "assigned_users": [],
    "subtasks": []
},
{
    "id": 19,
    "description": "fsdfdsfsd",
    "state": "started",
    "assigned_users": [],
    "subtasks": []
},
{
    "id": 20,
    "description": "Werner",
    "state": "new",
    "assigned_users": [],
    "subtasks": []
},
{
    "id": 21,
    "description": "teadfsd",
    "state": "done",
    "assigned_users": [],
    "subtasks": []
},
{
    "id": 22,
    "description": "task",
    "state": "new",
    "assigned_users": [],
    "subtasks": []
},
{
    "id": 23,
    "description": "asdasd",
    "state": "started",
    "assigned_users": [],
    "subtasks": []
},
{
    "id": 24,
    "description": "asdasd",
    "state": "new",
    "assigned_users": [
        {
            "username": "hugo",
            "fullname": "Hugo Johnsson"
        }
    ],
    "subtasks": []
}
```

]

Answer (score 5):

You should sort the data before creating the `ListView`. You can use basic [dart sort method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/List/sort.html). Basically you just need to implement the [compare function](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Comparator.html) which returns an integer that the sign of the return value specify items order.

Read this example code for better understanding:

```dart
enum TaskState {
  newTask, done, started
}

class Task {
  Task(this.id, this.state);
  final int id;
  final TaskState state;

  String toString() {
    return "$id";
  }
}

int compare(TaskState a, TaskState b) {
  if (a == b) return 0;
  switch(a) {
    case TaskState.newTask:
      return -1;
      break;
    case TaskState.started:
      if(b == TaskState.newTask) return 1;
      return -1;
      break;
    case TaskState.done:
      return 1;
      break;
  }
}

void main() {
  List<Task> list = [
    Task(1, TaskState.done),
    Task(3, TaskState.newTask),
    Task(4, TaskState.started),
    Task(2, TaskState.done),
    Task(10, TaskState.newTask),
  ];
  list.sort((a, b) => compare(a.state, b.state));
  print(list);
}
```

**Implementing in your code should be something like this**

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<ProjectTask>>(
  future: someQuery(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snap) {
    snap.data.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a == b) return 0;
      switch(a) {
        case "new":
          return -1;
          break;
        case "started":
          if(b == "new") return 1;
          return -1;
          break;
        case "done":
          return 1;
          break;
      }
    });
    return ListView.builder(
      ...
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks man, can you explain how I would implement this in a good way? :)

Comment: It's actually pretty simple. I've edited the answer and added a implementation

Answer (score 2):

I found this helpful article with a great example to sort a list of objects by any field: https://www.kindacode.com/article/sorting-lists-in-dart/

Example:

```
 class User {
  String name;
  int age;

  User(this.name, this.age);

  @override
  toString() {
    return ('$name - $age years old \n');
  }
}

void main() {
  List<User> users = [
    User('Plumber', 10),
    User('John Doe', 50),
    User('Pipi', 4),
    User('Invisible Man', 31),
    User('Electric Man', 34)
  ];

  // Age from small to large
  users.sort((a, b) => a.age.compareTo(b.age));
  print('Age ascending order: ${users.toString()}');

  // Age from large to small
  users.sort((a, b) => b.age.compareTo(a.age));
  print('Age descending order: ${users.toString()}');
}
```