# Sort Firebase Data from AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> with Dart .sort() Function

Tags: firebase, flutter, sorting, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble sorting data after a Firebase query. In my database, there is a collection of `bikes`, and each bike has a condition: `Excellent`, `Great`, `Good`, `Fair`, `Poor`, or `Totaled`. I would like to sort by condition so the start of the list is `Excellent` and the bottom is `Totaled`. I am then putting this in a `ListView`.

My Firebase structure:
[My Firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUztx.png)

My query: `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('bikes').snapshots();`

I tried following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855619/flutter-sorting-listview-items-based-on-type)'s guidance, but to no avail. My very simple test below to sort by title length doesn't seem to sort anything (I'm passing the sorting to a function since sorting is only when the user clicks a button).

```
AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> sortSnapshot(
      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> snapshot) {
    if (sortList == true) {
        snapshot.data!.docs.sort((a, b) => a['Name'].length.compareTo(b['Name'].length));
    }
    return snapshot;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

For anyone stumbling across this in the future: mmcdon20's answer was correct. It turns out the AsyncSnapshot is indeed immutable. I didn't get any warnings or errors when trying to sort it (which is sort of annoying), but it makes sense. It couldn't be changed, so it wasn't changing.

Anyways, I ended up modifying my sorting function as follows:

My query: `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('bikes').snapshots();`

Extraction of mutable List to sort:

```
var snapList = snapshot.data!.docs.toList(); // <-- Mutable List object
var posts = sortSnapshot(snapList);          // <-- Function that sorts
```

My sorting function:

```
List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>> sortSnapshot(
      List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>> snapList) {
    if (sortString == 'Sort by: Distance') {
      // Grab lat/lon
      // Do distance calculation via Haversine formula
      // Sort by distance
    } else if (sortString == 'Sort by: Condition') {
      snapList.sort((a, b) => compareCondition(a['Condition'], b['Condition']));
    }
    return snapList;
  }
```

I haven't implemented the sorting by Distance yet, but you get the idea. For sorting by condition, here's my comparator:

```
int compareCondition(String a, String b) {
    // Order: Excellent, Great, Good, Fair, Poor, Totaled
    if (a == b) return 0;
    switch (a) {
      case "Excellent":
        return -1;
      case "Great":
        if (b == 'Excellent') return 1;
        return -1;
      case "Good":
        if ((b == 'Excellent') || (b == 'Great')) return 1;
        return -1;
      case "Fair":
        if ((b == 'Excellent') || (b == 'Great') || (b == 'Great')) return 1;
        return -1;
      case "Poor":
        if ((b == 'Excellent') ||
            (b == 'Great') ||
            (b == 'Great') ||
            (b == 'Fair')) return 1;
        return -1;
      case "Totaled":
        if ((b == 'Excellent') ||
            (b == 'Great') ||
            (b == 'Great') ||
            (b == 'Fair') ||
            (b == 'Poor')) return 1;
        return -1;
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

This properly sorts the list, and I can then use my `posts` List object to generate my `ListTiles` in my `ListView`.

Thanks `mmcdon20` and hopes this helps someone out someday!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the sorting part is your problem here. The following code sorts the items by length of `Name` using the same approach you provided above, and then sorts by condition:

```dart
void main() {
  final conditions = {
    'Excellent': 0,
    'Great': 1,
    'Good': 2,
    'Fair': 3,
    'Poor': 4,
    'Totaled': 5,
  };

  final docs = [
    {'Name': 'Argon', 'Condition': 'Great'},
    {'Name': 'Baum', 'Condition': 'Good'},
    {'Name': 'Canyon', 'Condition': 'Excellent'},
    {'Name': 'Davidson', 'Condition': 'Totaled'},
    {'Name': 'Erickson', 'Condition': 'Fair'},
    {'Name': 'Focus', 'Condition': 'Poor'},
  ];

  docs.sort((a, b) => a['Name']!.length.compareTo(b['Name']!.length));

  print(docs);

  docs.sort((a, b) =>
    conditions[a['Condition']]!.compareTo(conditions[b['Condition']]!));

  print(docs);
}
```

<strike>I think a more likely explanation for what is happening, is you are not updating the UI by calling `setState` or something along those lines. Or maybe your `sortList` variable is assigned to `false`. Or maybe you aren't correctly registering the function as a callback to the aforementioned button press. There really isn't enough context here to say for certain, but I really don't think your sorting code is the problem here.</strike>

Edit. After looking at it a bit more. Why are you passing around and trying to update an `AsyncSnapshot` object? The [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html) suggests that this class is immutable. I presume calling `.data` on this object generates the data every time you call the method, rather than returning a mutable reference (otherwise the class could not possibly be immutable).

Essentially what I think you will need to do is save `snapshot.data!.docs` to a variable, and sort and return that, rather than returning back the `AsyncSnapshot`.

Comment: I was passing it around just to free up some space in my Widget tree. Also to help with filtering... essentially my order of operations is: 1) Make query with any added filters, 2) Sort the returned query.

However, I did not realize it was immutable.... that is a bit concerning and maybe explains why nothing happened with my function. I'll try your recommendation of saving it as a variable and passing that back! It's just all a bit confusing since the snapshot has so much extra info that I don't really need. I have to dig down to the actual list object to get to the relevant fields.